# How can I build this simple regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to build a regex to match:
lowercase letters,
numbers,
underscore and
length should be between 4 and 16 characters (both included);

```
/[a-z0-9_]{4,16}/g
```

This should be strait on, but my code is braking (in the context of the challenge I'm in). Even though is passing on RegExr.com.

It's hard to see whats wrong because its giving me the right match online. 
I've tried to see some tutorials but I believe that the regex is correct, although I can't figure whats wrong...

Comment: can you give example on what is not working ? maybe some cases to try.

Comment: Perhaps use anchors `^[a-z0-9_]{4,16}$`

Comment: is failing on these two:'Hasd_12assssssasasasasasaasasasasas', 'asd43 34'

Comment: It needs to be anchored, otherwise it will match a substring.

Comment: @TiagoRuivo the second example fails correctly, there is a space which is not a character you mentioned

Comment: ^[a-z0-9_]{4,16}$ this did the trick... Of course, it was so obvious, when you are trying to match a password...

Comment: thanks guys... I've sorted it!!!!